# Find all complex numbers z for this equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have been practicing some complex numbers and came across this problem.

Find all the complex numbers z that satisfie the equation $z + |z| = 8+4i$

I have said that $z = x + yi$ which means $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which makes the equation

$x + yi + \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 8 + 4i$ but I dont know how to go from here to a solution?

Do I just have to rearrange a little or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: x and y are real number, then the square root is a real number. You can find the value the only component on the left that is imaginary is "yi", so y=4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may first identify real part and imaginary part:

$$x + yi + \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 8 + 4i\implies x+ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}=8, yi=4i $$

$$ y=4,  x+ \sqrt{x^2 +16}=8 $$

$$x=3, y=4 \implies z=3+4i$$

Answer (score 3):

You have that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x-8=(4-y)i.$$ The LHS is real. So, the RHS must be real. Thus $y=4.$ Now you only need to solve

$$\sqrt{x^2+4^2}+x-8=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

From $z + |z| = 8+4i$ and $z=x+iy$ we get $|z|=8-x+i(4-y) \in \mathbb R$, hence $y=4$ , $|z|=8-x$ and $z=x+4i$. Thus

$$(8-x)^2=|z|^2=x^2+16.$$

This gives $x=3$ and $z=3+4i$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you would have been able to go further if you had been **precise** in what you tried:

> Let $x,y$ be **reals** such that $z = x+yi$.

You can do this **because** this is how complex numbers are defined. And then it should immediately become obvious what to do next after you got your expression:

> $x+yi+\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 8+4i$.

Again, by definition of complex numbers, two complex numbers are equal only if both real and imaginary parts match. That is why we rearrange and isolate real/imaginary parts (based on the fact that $x,y$ are real):

> $(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-8)+(y-4)i = 0+0i$.

And then the rest is easy; you get two equations, one for the real part and one for the imaginary part.

You can alternatively compare directly as done in other answers, but you should **know and understand** that when doing so you are effectively doing the same, or equivalently using the following properties:

> $Re(z+w) = Re(z)+Re(w)$ for any complex $z,w$.
>
> $Im(z+w) = Im(z)+Im(w)$ for any complex $z,w$.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as $\,z = 8+4i - |z|\,$, then taking conjugates on both sides gives $\,\bar z = 8 - 4i - |z|\,$, and multiplying the two:

$$\require{cancel}
|z|^2 = \left(8+4i - |z|\right)\left(8-4i - |z|\right) = 80 - 16 |z| + |z|^2 \;\;\implies\;\; |z|=5
$$

Then $\,z = 8+4i - |z|=3+4i\,$.